# how to play video with exoplayer ( exoplayer error on android 5 )

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

```
MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.4D401F, -1, null, [720, 480, 24.999622], [-1, -1]), format_supported=NO_EXCEEDS_CAPABILITIES
```

I get a high error when playing video or audio on Android 5

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Part of the error message states `format_supported=NO_EXCEEDS_CAPABILITIES`. It looks like exoplayer is failing stating that the video format you are trying to play is not supported because it exceeds the capabilities of the device.

This documentation outlines supported media types by Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats and for AVC there is a "Baseline Profile" that is supported with Android 3.0+, and a Main Profile that is supported on Android 6+

If you check this documentation [https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats) you'll see that `avc1.4D401F` falls under "Main Profile", so it will not run on Android 5.